# Anatomy of mature juice vesicles in hesperidium fruit?

Tags: botany, fruit

What is the cellular structure of mature [juice vesicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juice_vesicles)?

In a mature juice vesicle what cell types are present, how are they arranged and does this differ between species?

Comment: Can you provide any references describing what you mean? Why do you want to know? Editing your answer to add more information may make it easier to answer.

Comment: Sorry can’t find any references

Comment: In a mature juice vesicle what cells are present ,how are they arranged and does this differ between species

Comment: I have edited your question to include more info

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a look at [this paper linked through the wikipedia page](https://zenodo.org/records/1235688). It has a variety of information about the structure and distribution of juice vesicles across different types of fruit e.g.:

> The distribution of vesicles among segments
> within the same fruit was similar (fig. 3). The un-
> attached terminal ends of all vesicles exhibit a dis-
> tinct orientation within the carpel; these terminals
> point slightly toward the stylar end of the fruit. The
> seeds within the segment are oriented so that the
> chalazal end extends toward the stem end and the
> micropylar end extends toward the stylar end of the
> fruit.

> Most citrus fruit possess roughly 130-400 ves-
> icles per segment (table 1). Pummelo fruits contain
> the most vesicles per fruit, followed in order of
> decreasing vesicles per fruit by grapefruit, citron,
> sweet orange, meyer lemon, papeda, lemon, sour
> orange, mandarin, Satsuma mandarin, Citrus
> miaray, trifoliate orange, Gabon cherty-orange, and
> kumquat

etc. You should be able to answer most of your questions by reading that fully, but if there are follow up questions that come up, you should feel free to post another question.

Comment: What is the nature of the fluid filled cavity?                                            Is it a coenocyte? A schizogenous cavity? Perhaps a lysogenous cavity?

Comment: @Harrychink did you read the paper?

Comment: Indeed I did read the paper

Comment: If you are interested in the histology, I advise you to look on the first page at the section beginning with the sentence "_To 
summarize these past studies, juice vesicles are initiated just before or during anthesis as multicellular primordial bulges on the locular side of the endocarp surface usually on the radial wall._" See also the cited references.

Comment: I am still unable to find the nature of the cavity

Comment: @Harrychink This is written quite clearly in there, I'm not sure what the issue is: _The mature vesicles are elliptical multicellular sacs enclosed by a membrane, usually containing a minute oil gland in their center and connected to the segment wall by a multicellular stalk_. What about that doesn't answer your question when you read the paper? There's a lot more information there about its development, but at some point you have to sit down and read closely for the details you're interested in, I'm going to reproduce them all here for you.

Comment: What types of cell compose the vesicle?

Comment: What is the nature of the central cavity

Comment: I still do not know what cells compose the vesicle or what the nature of the central cavity is.

Comment: @Harrychink I have given you a variety of paths to follow to answer your question, and I've put as much effort as I care to into this answer given that you have put very little effort into your own research. I know that you're dissatisfied that I'm not going and copying everything here to satisfy you, and you're free to exercise your various options to express that dissatisfaction.

Comment: Please provide a source explaining the nature of the central cavity and/or the types of cell present in the mature vesicle

Comment: I am having trouble accessing the articles